# Como clonar un objeto en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando duplicar un viewmodel, `req` es un viewmodel del mismo tipo que `copiaReq` que me llega por parámetro

```
RequestMeetingRoom copiaReq = new RequestMeetingRoom();
copiaReq = req;
copiaReq.IdMeetingRoom = 3;
```

El problemas es que cuando le cambio el id a `copiaReq` tambien cambia en `req`. Como se puede evitar eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es usando la interfaz **[ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
class claseOriginal  : ICloneable
{
    public String titulo;
    public String descripcion;
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Implementando la interfaz y mediante Clone() se realiza la copia:

```
claseOriginal miClase = new claseOriginal();
//Copia de clase claseOriginal 
claseOriginal claseCopia = (claseOriginal)miClase.Clone();
```

Otra opción usando Deep Cloning:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
   ms.Position = 0;

   return (T) formatter.Deserialize(ms);
 }
}
```

Comment: En la mayoría de los posts de StackOverflow en inglés te encontrarás comentarios donde dicen que no debes implementar dicha interfaz. La razón es simple, para usar `MemberwiseClone()` no es necesaria dicha interfaz, además esta te obliga a estar casteando los objetos ya que la intefaz requiere que el tipo devuelto sea `object`. Lee http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/implement-icloneable-or-not

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente no necesitas clonar todo un grafo de objetos pero en caso que realmente lo necesites puede utilizar esta librería:

> **Disclaimer**: Yo soy el creador de la librería

**[Minicloner](https://github.com/carlosmunozrodriguez/minicloner)**

Esta libreria te permite hacer un deep cloning de **cualquier** objeto .NET incluyendo generics, dynamic, primitive types, referencias, circulares, etc.

El modo de uso es el sgte:

```
var cloner = new Minicloner.Cloner<RequestMeetingRoom>();
RequestMeetingRoom copiaReq = cloner.Clone(req);
copiaReq.IdMeetingRoom = 3;
```

Ahora si se cumple que luego de modificar el `IdMeetingRoom`:

`copiaReq.IdMeetingRoom != req.IdMeetingRoom`

Aún no hay un release formal del proyecto aunque pienso liberarlo ya pronto. Pero al ser un proyecto open source el fuente esta libre de ser usado.

Este es el link a los archivos relevante:

- [ICloner.cs](https://github.com/carlosmunozrodriguez/minicloner/blob/develop/src/Minicloner/ICloner.cs) (Interfaz del Cloner)
- [Cloner.cs](https://github.com/carlosmunozrodriguez/minicloner/blob/develop/src/Minicloner/Cloner.cs) (Clase principal)
- [FormatterServices.cs](https://github.com/carlosmunozrodriguez/minicloner/blob/develop/src/Minicloner/FormatterServices.cs) (En caso de que la versión de .NET Framework no soporte la clase `FormatterServices`)
- [StringReflectionExtensions.cs](https://github.com/carlosmunozrodriguez/minicloner/blob/develop/src/Minicloner/StringReflectionExtensions.cs) (En caso que la versión de .NET no soporte el método `String.Copy`)

Answer (score 1):

Tenia el mismo problema pero con una particularidad, mi objeto era una lista.
En este caso la solución es muy sencilla.  Coloca al final la palabra clave ToList().  Al realizar esto C# crea una nueva referencia para tu nuevo objeto:

```
var copiaReq = req.ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto ocurre porque las clases son [tipos de referencia](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Hay varias formas de resolverlo

**Implementar clonación**

```
     public class RequestMeetingRoom
     {

        public RequestMeetingRoom Clone()
        {
            return (RequestMeetingRoom)this.MemberwiseClone();
        } 
     }
```

Esto te creará un *shallow copy* o [*copia superficial*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clon_%28Programaci%C3%B3n%29). Creo que en tu caso es suficiente.

Aunque existe una interfaz llamada [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) se ha debatido mucho si se debe usar o no. Lee http://www.codinghelmet.com/?path=howto/implement-icloneable-or-not. En cualquier caso para usar el método `MemberwiseClone()` no es necesario implementarla por lo que queda a tu desición.

**Usar reflection**

Usando reflection puedes copiar todos los valores del objeto y copiar en profundidad los valores que son por referencia. Esto puede ser complicado y siempre depende del tipo de objeto que tengas ya que los valores pueden ser bastante complejos.

```
     public class RequestMeetingRoom
     {

        public RequestMeetingRoom Clone()
        {
            var t = new RequestMeetingRoom();
            var type = t.GetType();

            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var p = type.GetProperty(prop.Name);
                p.SetValue(t, p.GetValue(this));
            }

            return t;
        } 
     }
```

Esto tambien te crea una *copia superficial* (y sólo copia propiedades) pero es sólo para ilustrar el punto. Échale un vistazo a https://github.com/Burtsev-Alexey/net-object-deep-copy

**Serialización**

```
     using System.Runtime.Serialization;
     using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
     using System.IO;

     [Serializable]
     public class RequestMeetingRoom
     {

        public RequestMeetingRoom Clone()
        {
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (stream)
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, this);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (RequestMeetingRoom)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        } 
     }
```

Esto tiene la desventaja que debes usar los namespaces referenciados:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
System.IO
```

Además debes marcar tu clase como serializable y **todas instancias de clases** que contenga tu objeto deben ser serializables también para que pueda funcionar.

**Usar [Automapper](http://automapper.org/)**

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<RequestMeetingRoom, RequestMeetingRoom>();
    Mapper.Map<RequestMeetingRoom, RequestMeetingRoom>(copiaReq , req);
```

Esta es usualmente la más sencilla ya que la librería es robusta y se encarga de todo el trabajo pesado.