# Problema al clonar una entidad con hijos c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, linq

Estoy clonando un objeto que contiene hijos, en este caso es variantesListCheck, cuando ejecuto esta opcion el identificador de variantesListCheck, se modifica junto con el original, pero solo desea que se cambie la copia, alguna idea?

```
    List<Orden2> copiarOrdenLista = editarOrdenLista.Where(p => p.GrupoID == ids.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
                                        List<Orden2> nuevaOrdenLista = new List<Orden2>();
                                        Guid nuevoGrupoID = Guid.NewGuid();
    
                                        foreach (var item in copiarOrdenLista)
                                        {
                                            var nuevo = item.Clone();
                                            nuevo.GrupoID = nuevoGrupoID;
    
                                            if (null != item.gruposLista && item.gruposLista.Any()) {
                                                //nuevo.gruposLista = item.gruposLista.Select(p => p.Clone()).ToList();
                                                List<GrupoCheck> _grupoLista = new List<GrupoCheck>();
                                                _grupoLista = item.gruposLista.Select(p => p).ToList();
    
                                                foreach (var _g in _grupoLista)
                                                {
                                                    _g.SetNewGuids(Guid.NewGuid());
                                                    
                                                    var variantes = new List<VariantesCheck>();
                                                    foreach (var mod in _g.variantesListCheck)
                                                    {
                                                        variantes.Add(mod);
                                                        //mod.setIndentificador(Guid.NewGuid());
                                                    }
                                                    _g.variantesListCheck = variantes;
                                                    _g.variantesListCheck.ForEach(x => x.setIndentificador(Guid.NewGuid()) );
                                                }
// al aplicar el setNewGuids este cambia la lista original tambien, junto con la copia.
                                                //_gruposLista.ForEach(x => x.SetNewGuids());
                                                nuevo.gruposLista = _grupoLista;
    
                                                //nuevo.variantesLista = item.variantesLista.Select(p => p.Clone()).ToList();                                        
                                            }
    
                                            nuevaOrdenLista.Add(nuevo);
                                        }
```

Clases que uso

```
 [Serializable]
    public class GrupoCheck : grupo_modificadores
    {
        public Guid Identificador { get; private set; }
 
        public List<VariantesCheck> variantesListCheck { get; set; }

        public GrupoCheck() : base()
        {
            this.Identificador = Guid.NewGuid();
            this.variantesListCheck = new List<VariantesCheck>();
        }

        public GrupoCheck Clone()
        { 
            var clone = (GrupoCheck)this.MemberwiseClone();
           
            return clone;
        }

        public void SetNewGuids(Guid id) {

            this.Identificador = id;
 
        }
    }

   [Serializable]
    public class VariantesCheck : lista_grupoMod_modificadores_dto
    {
        public Guid Identificador { get; private set; }
         
        public VariantesCheck() : base()
        {
            this.Identificador = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        public void setIndentificador(Guid identificador) {
            this.Identificador = identificador;
        }

         
    }
```

Comment: Eso es porque cuando trabajas con clases estas trabajando con objetos de referencia, los dos apuntan al mismo lugar de memoria, tenes que usar ICloneable, mira en esta respuesta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20123/como-clonar-un-objeto-en-c

Comment: edite la pregunta. agregando las clases, en si ya implemento la clonacion con this.MemberwiseClone

Comment: El método `MemberwiseClone` crea una copia superficial del objeto y copia todos sus campos, si un campo es de tipo valor, realiza una copia bit a bit, pero si un campo es de tipo referencia, al objeto clonado, solo se copia la referencia, por consiguiente, el objeto original y su clon se refieren al mismo objeto hijo. Para lograr que se modifique solo la copia y no los objetos originales, tienes que crear tu propio método `Clone`  o bien `new MemberwiseClone` y copiar de manera manual todos los campos; si se requiere, debes llamar al método `Clone` de los campos de tipo referencia.

Answer (score 0):

pues, eso es el tema de lo reference types, es decir, cuando una copia un reference type (una clase), lo que realmente esta copiando es la referencia de esa clase mas no el objeto per se, por que que ambas clases (original y copia) son esencialmente el mismo objeto.
Eso va tambien para los references types hijos que dicha clase pueda tener en tu caso "variantesListCheck", hay varias formar de solucionar este tema, la forma mas sencilla de solucionarlo es crear una nueva instancia y hacer una igualdad con cada uno de sus miembros, siempre y cuando la cantidad de miembros no sea muy extensa. Por ejemplo:

```
void Main()
{
    ClasePadre claseOriginal = new ClasePadre();
    ClasePadre claseCopiar = new ClasePadre
    {
        numero1 = claseOriginal.numero1,
        numero2 = claseOriginal.numero2,
        //ETC
        clase1 = new ClaseHijo
        {
            numero5 = claseOriginal.clase1.numero5,
        }
    }
}

public class ClasePadre
{
    int numero1;
    int numero2;
    int numero3;
    int numero4;
    ClaseHijo clase1;
}

public class ClaseHijo
{
    int numero5;
    int numero6;
}
```