# Cómo clonar un objeto cuya clase tiene una lista de objetos

Tags: c#, lista, objeto, clone

He visto en el foro como clonar un objeto:
[Como clonar un objeto en c#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20123/como-clonar-un-objeto-en-c)

Esto me ha ayudado, pero lo que quiero es clonar un objeto cuya clase tiene una lista de objetos. Tengo la clase FicheroLogos a la que ya he añadido el código en Clone() para poder clonar objetos de esta clase. Se clonan todos los parámetros excepto la lista de objetos List listaDeLogos:

```
    public class FicheroLogos : ICloneable
    {
        public string trayectoriaYnombre = "";
        public string etiquetaDelSubmenu = "";
        public string urlIcono = "";
        public Image icono = null;
        public List<Logo> listaDeLogos = new List<Logo>();
        public int contadorDeErrores;

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

La clase Logo es:

```
    public class Logo: ICloneable
    {
        public string nombre;
        public string urlLogo;
        public Image imagen;
        public string grupo;
        public bool error = false;

        public object Clone()
        {
            return this.MemberwiseClone();
        }
    }
```

El código que escribo es el siguiente (y no sé si esto es del todo eficiente porque ejecuto un bucle for que no se si es necesario). (ficheroLogosCopia y ficheroLogosOrigen y están creados).

```
    ficheroLogosCopia = (FicheroLogos)ficheroLogosOrigen.Clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < ficheroLogosOrigen.listaDeLogos.Count; i++) { ficheroLogosCopia.listaDeLogos[i] = (Logo)ficheroLogosOrigen.listaDeLogos[i].Clone(); }
    ficheroLogosAeditar.trayectoriaYnombre = "nueva trayectoria";
    ficheroLogosAeditar.listaDeLogos[0].nombre = "nuevo nombre";
```

El parámetro trayectoriaYnomre está clonado porque no se modifica en los dos objetos, pero el nombre del primer logo se modifica en los dos objetos porque no está clonado.
En el hilo que menciono al principio se explica que para clonar una lista se puede añadir .ToList() al final para crea una nueva referencia para tu nuevo objeto:

```
ficheroLogosCopia.listaDeLogos = ficheroLogosOrigen.listaDeLogos.ToList();
```

pero no funciona, y no se si es por ser una lista de objetos. Si se hace con una lista de tipos básicos como un string, entonces si funciona:

```
List<string> lista1 = new List<string>(){ "a", "b,", "c"};
List<string> lista2 = new List<string>();
lista2 = lista1.ToList();
lista2[0] = "nuevo valor";
```

Bueno, pues mi pregunta es esa, ¿Cómo puedo clonar un objeto que tiene una lista de objetos?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto no clonará cada elemento de la lista, pero creará una nueva lista

```
var logosCopiados = new List<Logo>(listaDeLogos);
```

Si desea clonar cada elemento de la lista, con la implementación de `ICloneable` en `Logo`:

```
var logoCopiados  = new List<Logo>(listaDeLogos.Select(x => x.Clone()));
```

Entonces dentro de `Clone()` de la clase `FicheroLogos` se haría lo siguiente:

```
public object Clone()
{
    var ficheroLogoTemp = (FicheroLogos) this.MemberwiseClone();
   
    if(ficheroLogoTemp.listaDeLogos is not null)
    {
        var listaLogoTemp = ficheroLogoTemp.listaDeLogos.Select(x => x.Clone() as Logo);
        var copiaListaLogo = new List<Logo>(listaLogoTemp);
        ficheroLogoTemp.listaDeLogos = copiaListaLogo;
    }
            
    return ficheroLogoTemp;
}
```